# Indexing token bigrams in Lucene

Tags: indexing, lucene

I need to index bi-grams of words (tokens) in Lucene. I can produce n-grams and than index them, but I am wondering if there is something in Lucene which will do this for me.
I found out that Lucene indexes only n-gram of chars. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the NGramTokenizer:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

The class that you are looking for is the ShingleFilter: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you need to index bi-grams, [SpanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) and/or [SnowballAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html) may be helpful.